# How to transpose columns into rows in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to transpose some columns of my table to row. I'm using Java and Spark 2.1.2. Here is my  table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+  
|  A  |col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|   
+-----+-----------------+------+    
|  1  |  0.0|  0.6|  0.8| 0.9|   
|  2  |  0.6|  0.7|  0.7| 1.2|   
|  3  |  0.5|  0.9|  1.8| 9.1|  
|  ...|  ...|  ...|  ...| ...|
```

I would like to have somthing like this:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+    
|  A  | col_id | col_value |  
+-----+--------+-----------+  
|  1  |   col_1|        0.0|  
|  1  |   col_2|        0.6|     
|  1  |   col_3|        0.8|  
| ... |    ... |        ...|     
|  2  |   col_1|        0.6|  
|  2  |   col_2|        0.7|   
|  ...|     ...|        ...|    
|  3  |   col_1|        0.5|  
|  3  |   col_2|        0.9|  
|  ...|     ...|        ...| and so on
```

Does someone know haw I can do it? I know the solution exists for Python but I am trying to do it using Java.

I tried this method

```
 df.selectExpr("stack(4, 'col_1', col_1, 'col_2', col_2', col_3', col_3,'col_4', col_4)as (Key,Value)");
```

But its not working.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get the result using above approach. It turns out i was using SparkContext instead of SQLContext using which it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution By using Spark-scala:

```
def transpose(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame, transposeUsing: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
import spark.implicits._
val (cols, types) = df.dtypes.filter{ case (c, _) => !transposeUsing.contains(c)}.unzip

val kvdf = explode(array(cols.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias("column_name"),col(c).alias("column_value"))): _*))

val constantCols = transposeUsing.map(col(_))

df.select(constantCols :+ kvdf.alias("_kvdf"): _*)
  .select(constantCols ++ Seq($"_kvdf.column_name", $"_kvdf.column_value"): _*)
}
 //call the function
transpose(df, Seq("A")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Goutam Pradhan. However i was looking for answer in Java and with few iterations i was able to get it.